# .htaccess force HTTPS and non-www on htm pages

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

*UPDATE:
After hours of searching still had no solution so I had to change/update my question:*

I have few pages with parameters manualy converted to .htm using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^MyPage1.htm$ cart.php?rid=1 [L,NC]
```

I have tested diffrent solutions and non of them works fully:

**CODE 1:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

**RESULT 1:**

`http://example.com/randompage.php`   ->  `http://example.com/randompage.php` **[NOT WORKING]**
`http://www.example.com/randompage.php`   ->  `https://example.com/randompage.php` [WORKING]
`https://www.example.com/randompage.php`  ->  `https://example.com/randompage.php` [WORKING]

`http://example.com/MyPage1.htm`      ->  `http://example.com/MyPage1.htm` **[NOT WORKING]**
`http://www.example.com/MyPage1.htm`  ->  `https://example.com/MyPage1.htm` [WORKING]
`https://www.example.com/MyPage1.htm` ->  `https://example.com/MyPage1.htm` [WORKING]

**CODE 2**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**CODE 3**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**RESULT 2 & 3** (Same results)

`http://example.com/randompage.php`   ->  `https://example.com/randompage.php` [WORKING]
`http://www.example.com/randompage.php`   ->  `https://example.com/randompage.php` [WORKING]
`https://www.example.com/randompage.php`  ->  `https://example.com/randompage.php` [WORKING]

`http://example.com/MyPage1.htm`      ->  `http://example.com/MyPage1.htm` **[NOT WORKING]**
`http://www.example.com/MyPage1.htm`  ->  `https://example.com/MyPage1.htm` [WORKING]
`https://www.example.com/MyPage1.htm` ->  `https://example.com/MyPage1.htm` [WORKING]

Comment: Is the HTTPS redirect right at the top?

Comment: Yes this redirect to HTTPS but only php pages.

Comment: Please can you show your entire `.htaccess` file?

Comment: My entire htaccess has almost 500lines most nothing to do with mod_rewirte.

Comment: Right, I see. Well, if the HTTPS redirect rule is declared as the first rule, then I don't see what the problem could be.

Comment: HTTPS Rule it is working but not for manual HTML redirections created in .htaccess

Comment: Yeah, I get that - my point is that it should be working if it is the first redirect, no matter what is requested. Perhaps you could try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` instead?

Comment: I suggest you enable `RewriteLog` and then post the output of logs for  `http://example.com/MyPage1.htm` URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike Rockett mentioned in the comment, make sure the redirect rule is before the `RewriteRule ^MyPage1.htm$ cart.php?rid=1 [L,NC]`.  You don't want the `[L]` stopping evaluation of later rules.

If that doesn't do the trick, try turning on advanced logging by putting `LogLevel trace6` in your .htaccess and then look at the Apache error log to see what is actually happening with the rewrite rules.

Also, another thing that can mess you up in development of redirects is that they can get cached, so even if you fix the problem, things are still broken.  I'm not saying that's likely the case in this situation but just something to be aware of.  I recommend just using `[R]` instead of `[R=301]` until you've confirmed it's working to avoid this issue.  If you suspect caching, you can try opening another browser that you haven't used yet on this like IE / Firefox / Chrome.

Comment: I'm learning something new every day. Order of rules are important!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the OR operator with a single protocol and domain specific rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```